# Why do we use two optical modes per qubit in the KLM scheme?

Tags: experimental-realization, photonics

The original [KLM paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/35051009) says:

The basic states of a bosonic qubit encoded in modes $l_1$ and $l_2$ are $|0\rangle\mapsto|0\rangle_{l_1}|1\rangle_{l_2}$ and $|1\rangle\mapsto|1\rangle_{l_1}|0\rangle_{l_2}$.

Why couldn't we simply encode qubits as $|0\rangle\mapsto|0\rangle_{l_1}$ and $|1\rangle\mapsto|1\rangle_{l_1}$?

Comment: How would you implement the coherent gates? It's super to move photons between modes than to create and annihilate them...

Comment: Would it be correct to say that moving between modes is linear optics while creating a photon in a mode is nonlinear?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, both options are ok. You can use "single-rail" or "dual-rail" encoding. Dual-rail has some implementation advantages. Look here for example :
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.6071.pdf